# Do Windows permissions on removable drives apply to any system the drive is connected to?

Tags: windows, usb-storage

When I set permissions on a usb drive, will they remain when I connect it to another system? I assume not, because they refer to users on the original system, correct?

Comment: What do you mean by “permissions”? Most removable media is formatted with FAT32 by default which does not support permissions. If your removable drive is formatted as NTFS, then it will support permissions, and they will indeed carry to other systems because the permissions are encoded on the drive itself. However, they may not mean anything if the users assigned don’t exist on the other systems and you will probably not even see the name in the ACL. You can of course, create the users and assign them the appropriate SID. Standard permissions like *everyone*, etc. will work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the permissions you set, and whether the users have the same IDs on all the machines.

In a domain environment, all users will have the same IDs on all computers so permissions will apply on all computers in the environment.

In a home environment, the default users on Windows will be the same across all computers.
The Administrator, Guest, Everyone, and System accounts for example, will all have the same permissions applied on all Windows computers as they have the same IDs across all computers.

Custom created users won't have the same ID on any other computer, so if a directory on the USB drive was set to full permissions for `User A` on `Computer A` only, then `User A` on `computer B` won't be able to access the directory unless the ID was the same.